# Input loses focus after typing in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to create a reusable component to manage every form field.

Unfortunatelly, after typing a letter I am losing focus of my input. I think this behaviour is a result of re-rendering the parent component.

I would like to find a easy solution to this problem. Take on account that although formData and error are received from a hook, the behaviour would be exactly the same if we set an useState and its initialValues (an empty object).

```
export const PersonInnerFormComponent = ({
  formData,
  onChange,
  error,
}: {
  formData: IPerson;
  onChange: any;
  error?: PersonError;
}) => {
  const TextInput = ({ id, name }: { id: string; name: string }) => {
    return (
      <FormGroup>
        <Col sm="2">
          <FormLabel column htmlFor={id}>
            {name}
          </FormLabel>
        </Col>
        <Col sm="10">
          <FormControl
            key={id}
            type="text"
            id={id}
            placeholder={name}
            value={formData[id as keyof IPerson]}
            onChange={onChange}
            error={error?.payload[id]}
          />
        </Col>
      </FormGroup>
    );
  };

  return (
    <>
      <TextInput id="type" name="Type" />
      <TextInput id="name" name="Name" />
    </>
  );
};

const PersonFormComponent = ({
  error,
  ...props
}: IPersonFormComponentProps) => {
  const { formData, onChange, onSubmit } = useFormPerson(
    props.onSubmit,
    props.person
  );

  return (
    <PersonFormWrapper>
      <Form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
        <PersonInnerFormComponent
          formData={formData}
          onChange={onChange}
          error={error}
        />
        {props.onCancel && (
          <Button
            variant="outline-dark"
            className="mr-3 text-capitalize btn-default"
            onClick={props.onCancel}
          >
            Cancelar
          </Button>
        )}{' '}
        <Button variant="success" type="submit">
          Guardar
        </Button>{' '}
      </Form>
    </PersonFormWrapper>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

@Alvaro here you have a `sandbox` to explain what is the error: https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-galois-du8d7o?file=/src/App.js

The problem is that each time `PersonInnerFormComponent` is rendered a new `TextInput` component is created (and that's why the text goes away). To avoid this you should define the `TextInput` component outside `PersonInnerFormComponent`